# Security patch update issue in Magento EE 1.14.3.2

Tags: patches, magento-1.14

I am trying to install security patch `SUPEE-9767` but following error coming while applying patch please help to fix this issue.

```
> [root@sip5-204 html]$ sh PATCH_SUPEE-9767_EE_1.14.2.2_v1-2017-05-22-09-08-55.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/community/OnTap/Merchandiser/Model/Resource/Merchandiser.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 156 (offset 16 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/CatalogEvent/controllers/Adminhtml/Catalog/EventController.php
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/GiftWrapping/Model/Wrapping.php
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/Invitation/Model/Config.php
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/Invitation/Model/Invitation.php
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/Invitation/controllers/IndexController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 60.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Enterprise/Invitation/controllers/IndexController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/Invitation/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/Invitation/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Helper/Form/Key.php
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Observer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Checkout/Formkey.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Symlink.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Date.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Zend/Cache.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Xml/Excel.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Uploader.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Instance.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Helper/Image.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/merchandiser.xml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/symlink.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/customerbalance/checkout/onepage/payment/additional.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/giftcardaccount/multishipping/payment.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/giftcardaccount/onepage/payment/scripts.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/invitation/form.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/layout/page.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/template/customerbalance/checkout/onepage/payment/additional.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/template/giftcardaccount/multishipping/payment.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/template/giftcardaccount/onepage/payment/scripts.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/template/invitation/form.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/enterprise/template/reward/checkout/onepage/payment/additional.phtml
patching file app/etc/config.xml
patching file app/locale/en_US/Enterprise_Invitation.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Dataflow.csv
patching file app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv
patching file downloader/Maged/Connect.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.js
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js
patching file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.map
patching file js/varien/payment.js
patching file skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
patching file skin/frontend/enterprise/default/js/opcheckout.js
```

Comment: it is supee 9767 v2 is working now?

Comment: @marius, this is not a duplicate question. It's rather a specific problem deriving from the more general issue. I would love to answer this question and explain how it's tackled, but the question is locked now for answering. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `Hunk #1 FAILED at 60`. error because

```
app/code/core/Enterprise/Invitation/controllers/IndexController.php
```

core file differ from original Magento 1.14.3.2 version. Compare with 1.14.3.2 core file any changes are space in core file.

Comment: I will provide in detail

Comment: For any help on Security patch you can ask. I worked a lot in Security patch

Comment: OK first i'll compare with original file and i'll update Rama Chandran

Comment: both files are same but still errro is coming

Comment: wait now v2 patches coming. we need to revert the v1 and install v2 patches.https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-9767

Comment: I will surely help you. :)

Comment: you can install new patch any issue please ask.

Comment: v1 patch means which one your telling?

Comment: My Magento version is 1.14.2.2

Comment: Today release patch 2 please check the link

Comment: Can i Use this ,                                                                                            
 Security Patch - SUPEE-9767 - version EE 1.14.2.0-1.14.2.4 - V2
PATCH_SUPEE-9767_EE_1.14.2.4_v2-2017-07-11-10-45-11.sh
This v2 patch replaces the original SUPEE-9767. Previously installed SUPEE-9767 patch needs to be reverted prior to installing this version.

Comment: yes , also see what are changes https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183443/supee-9767-v2-possible-problems-and-solved-issues?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: if any issue please add in question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62204/discussion-between-jeeva-chezhiyan-and-rama-chandran).